# Where is mongodb config file located when running not as an Ubuntu service?

Tags: mongodb

### SITUATION

I know that it's better to run MongoDB instance on Ubuntu as a service, but on the moment of setting it up I was totally new to Linux & MongoDB and couldn't configure it to run NOT on the default location (mine default location was - system disks). So, what I did is just `sudo mongod --port 34234 --dbpath /path/to/another/disk`. To make it run forever I use `tmux` terminal sessions.

### PROBLEM

The thing is - i want to enable MongoDB remote access, and as it says [here](https://medium.com/founding-ithaka/setting-up-and-connecting-to-a-remote-mongodb-database-5df754a4da89), i need to do `sudo vim /etc/mongod.conf` which leads me to my default "service" MongoDB instance configuration.

What is the path to config file of "external" MongoDB instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you aren't running MongoDB as a service, there is (as at MongoDB 4.2) no default configuration file location. Locations for configuration files vary based on O/S and user preference, so the config file path is currently only set via service definitions when you install packaged versions of MongoDB.

For manual invocation you need to pass a config file path as a command line option using  `--config` (or the older & shorter `-f` alias):

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

or

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

If you are starting `mongod` manually, I would recommend saving all of your options (port, dbpath, etc) in a configuration file so your process runs with consistent options. If you are using MongoDB 4.2 or newer, there is an  [`--outputConfig` command-line option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-command-line-options-to-yaml/) for `mongod` that will helpfully convert your command-line options to the [YAML config file equivalents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/).

You also do not need to run `mongod` using `sudo`; the process can run as any user with appropriate file & directory permissions for full access to the configured dbpath & log path. Running as a user with more limited permissions is better security practice.

Answer (score 2):

As @Stennie pointed out, you can (and probably should for repeatability) refer to a config file using the command line.  I see in your original post you pass several parameters

```
mongod --port 34234 --dbpath /path/to/another/disk
```

Assuming you are using MongoDB 3.6 or later, you are defaulting to binding to localhost only, meaning privately accessible only.  You can pass an additional parameter to specify a network interface card by passing the  option `--bind_ip`.  Use the IP Address of the network card you would like the mongod to listen on.  An example of the call might look like ...

```
mongod --port 34234 --dbpath /path/to/another/disk --bind_ip 192.168.0.18
```

... assuming your servers internal IP address is 192.168.0.18.  You can open it up to the entire world (which is considered un-secure) by binding to 0.0.0.0.  This can be useful for development systems but never recommended for production systems.  For example...

```
mongod --port 34234 --dbpath /path/to/another/disk --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

With this setting you can test connectivity from another computer.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options for more details.